# Zigbee or Bluetooth for turning router on and off?

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, zigbee

I want to be able to turn my wifi router on and off with a smart plug. What would be the best way to achieve that? Have one special plug which is zigbee (or is Bluetooth better for this?) which only does this one thing? No hub, since I won't be using that outside of the home.

Commit to zigbee altogether and buy everything zigbee, which would mean that I would also need a hub of some sort?

Have everything in wifi and just have one bt plug for the router?

Generally, I plan for smart plugs, lamps and later on heat control.

Comment: how will you control the plug when the router is powered down?

Comment: @jsotola that's the question. With zigbee and bt I should be able to operate independent of the router.

Answer (score 2):

Sketch your use cases.

Is the smart plug activated by a person, or is it automated? Does the person use a smartphone? Are they in the same house? Same room? What would trigger the off action? What would trigger the on action?

Once you have these sketched out, the options should be pretty clear. For example, smartphones don't have Zigbee. Smart switches can come with dedicated remotes. Anything that requires the router itself will only work for the off action. That will eliminate most of your options. What's left?

Trying to solve the bigger picture (how to design your smart home) will take a lot more consideration. Focus on the task at hand first. Understand the constraints on that before you try to generalise.